# Classify the series as absolutely convergent, conditionally convergent, or divergent.

Tags: sequences-and-series

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}n}{2n+1}$

My answer is that the series diverges because:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |\frac{(-1)^{n+1}n}{2n+1}|$ = $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{2n+1}$ diverges as $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{n}{2n+1} = \frac {1} {2}$ so the sequence of partial sums does not converge.

I still feel that my answer lacks something, maybe why the series is not conditionally convergent. I really need some help!

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_n = \dfrac{ (-1)^{n+1} n }{2n + 1 }$. You claim that $\sum a_n$ diverges. Indeed. If you can show that $\lim a_n \neq 0$, then divergence follows. Since the sequence alternates, we may evaluate for different value of $n$. For instance, if $n$ is ${\bf even}$, then

$$ a_n = \dfrac{n}{2n+1} \to 1/2 $$

and if $n$ is ${\bf odd}$, then

$$ a_n = \dfrac{-n }{2n+1} \to - 1/2 $$

As $(a_n)$ approaches two different values, then $\lim a_n$ does not exist. In fact, it cannot be $0$ and thus your series diverges.

Answer (score 1):

You have shown that the series is not absolutely convergent because the magnitude of the general term does not have limit zero.

After your work, it is still possible for the series to be conditionally convergent; you have not shown that the series is divergent.  For that, you need that the limit of the general term does not exist (because the limit of the magnitudes is $1/2$, as you have already shown, and the signs of the terms alternate, so the limit doesn't even exist).

Answer (score 0):

Your answer covers the ' convergence' test also.

$|a_n| $ does not tend to zero implies $a_n$ does not tend to zero. So it fails to be convergent also.